# How to assign a list to a masked rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe which contains some nan values. I would like to assign a list ([5, 7, 8, 9]) to the new column D in the dataframe, but only for the rows with non-nan values in the column B.

So I created a mask (not_na_mask = df_test['B'].notna()) to indicate the rows which are not nan in the column B. Then I assign np.nan to the new column D. Now I need to assign the list to the masked rows. I tried df_test[not_na_mask]['D'] = labels , but it doesn't work and keeps np.nan in all the values in column D.

Number of the items in the list are same as the not_na_mask.sum().

You can find the sample df here:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar'],
                       'B' : [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 6, np.nan],
                       'C' : [2.0, np.nan, 8., 1., 2., 9.]})

df_test:

    A   B   C
0   foo 1.0 2.0
1   bar 2.0 NaN
2   foo NaN 8.0
3   bar 4.0 1.0
4   foo 6.0 2.0
5   bar NaN 9.0

not_na_mask = df_test['B'].notna()
df_test['D'] = np.nan

labels = [5, 7, 8, 9]

df_test[not_na_mask]['D'] = labels
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   foo 1.0 2.0 5.0
1   bar 2.0 NaN 7.0
2   foo NaN 8.0 NaN
3   bar 4.0 1.0 8.0
4   foo 6.0 2.0 9.0
5   bar NaN 9.0 NaN
```

Comment: Loop over resulting mask array and generate new column dynamically based on results. Assign new column to column D as values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If number of not misisng values is same like length of list `labels` you can use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
not_na_mask = df_test['B'].notna()
labels = [5, 7, 8, 9]
df_test.loc[not_na_mask, 'D'] = labels

print (df_test)
     A    B    C    D
0  foo  1.0  2.0  5.0
1  bar  2.0  NaN  7.0
2  foo  NaN  8.0  NaN
3  bar  4.0  1.0  8.0
4  foo  6.0  2.0  9.0
5  bar  NaN  9.0  NaN
```